# How to make loading/spinner bar active on lazy router loading in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I use the angular2.0 release version.
When I load a lazy router,If the router has a lot of code,It's almost 1MB，The browser needs to wait for some time,It's unfriendly,so I want create a loading animation.
Whether angular2 provided the event or directive?

sorry about my english is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is this:

- Set up a service that exposes a public flag through a BehaviorSubject/Observable. Let's call it `isLoading$`
- Use CanActivate to detect when lazy-loading starts: emit `true` on `isLoading$`
- When the module has loaded, emit `false` on `isLoading$` from the module's entry component's `onInit()`.
- Create a spinner or similar to indicate loading: `*ngIf="isLoading$ | async"`

Comment: Thanks, I found a way
`this.router.events.subscribe((event)=>{
            var isStart = event instanceof NavigationStart;
            var isEnd = event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof NavigationError;
            if(isStart)this.appProvider.PageIsLoading = true;
            if(isEnd)this.appProvider.PageIsLoading = false;
        });`